# Why use angularfire $destroy()?

Tags: angularfire

What is the reason that $destroy() exists in Angularfire?

The documentation of angularfire sais:

https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebasearray-destroy

*Stop listening for events and free memory used by this array (empties the local copy). Changes are no longer synchronized to or from Firebase.*

```
sync = $firebase(ref).$asArray();
...
....
sync.$destroy()
```

Can I not just do:

```
sync = null
```

or

```
delete sync
```

Or should I really use $destroy() for some reason?

Comment: [Looking at this line](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/src/FirebaseObject.js#L133) it appears you may not need to even call $destroy if you are destroying the scope.  If you are not destroying the scope you should be doing something similar to [this](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire-seed/blob/master/app/account/account.js#L8-L19)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `$destroy()` [exists to empty the data and unbind event listeners.](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/src/FirebaseObject.js#L392-L407)  If you need to unbind the `$firebaseArray()` or `$firebaseObject()` you could use `$destroy()` but I think it would be nicer to use the unbind function that is resolved.

This was code snippet was taken from [angularfire-seed](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire-seed/blob/master/app/account/account.js#L8-L19)

```
  var unbind;
  // create a 3-way binding with the user profile object in Firebase
  var profile = $firebaseObject(fbutil.ref('users', user.uid));
  profile.$bindTo($scope, 'profile').then(function(ub) { unbind = ub; });

  // expose logout function to scope
  $scope.logout = function() {
    if( unbind ) { unbind(); }
    profile.$destroy();
    ...
  };
```